# How to get the length of elements within this nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-table

I want to create/read an object of a table (column by column). My code goes here:

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var werteArray = [];
    var ueberschriftArray = [];
    $('#tabelleDateneingabe tbody tr').each(function() {
        werteArray.push($(this).children().eq(i).text());
    });
    $('#tabelleDateneingabe thead tr').each(function() {
        ueberschriftArray.push($(this).children().eq(i).text());
    });
    arr2.push({spalte: i, daten: {ueberschrift: ueberschriftArray, werte:werteArray}});
}
arr1.push(arr2);
```

This runs fine and produces this JSON:

```
[
[
    {
        "spalte": 0,
        "daten": {
            "ueberschrift": [
                "Spalte1"
            ],
            "werte": [
                "Zelle: 0_0",
                "Zelle: 1_0",
                "Zelle: 2_0",
                "Zelle: 3_0",
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "spalte": 1,
        "daten": {
            "ueberschrift": [
                "Spalte2"
            ],
            "werte": [
                "Zelle: 0_1",
                "Zelle: 1_1",
                "Zelle: 2_1",
                "Zelle: 3_1",
            ]
        }
    }]]
```

Now I want to go through this object in order to get the number of elements for every row.

I'm pretty sure this could be done by using length on the "werte" node, but how to access this value for every column ("spalte")?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should use a loop to access it.

Comment: @JayHarris: That's what i was trying for a while but with no success. I thought `$(arr1).each()...` gives me all arr2. Then i used `$(this).each()...` to access

Comment: What Jay said, or better yet, count it as you build the json. No point in looping twice.

Comment: maybe you could show us what you have tried...

Comment: well then go to [MDN for loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FStatements#Loop_Statements)

Comment: Addition to previous comment: to access all elements within arr2. Then i used `$(this).children().eq(0)` to acces the value of "spalte". I had no success so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return an array of numbers of entries in werte;

```
var rowCount = [];
for(var i=0;i<json[0].length;i++) {
    var rowArr = json[0][i].daten.werte;
    rowCount[i] = rowArr.length;
}
console.log(rowCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an "alternative" answer, since it's not the canonical way of doing it, but the approach  is so flexible you will find yourself wishing it could always be this easy...

May I suggest using "JSONPath":
http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

A library that allows you to query JSON objects similar to how XPath lets you query XML documents.

It would then be invoked in your example as `jsonPath(arr1,"..werte.*")` which returns the array of matching items, or  `jsonPath(arr1,"..werte.*").length` which of course returns the number of items in that array.